# How to sum over "i such that (i,j) in certain set" in AMPL

Tags: optimization, ampl

In AMPL, I'm working on a problem very similar to the node-colouring problem, but here I am trying to assign time slots to exams such that no two exams that share students take place at the same time. I have a set Exams, a set Students and a set Enrolled of pairs (i,j) such that exam i will be taken by student j.

I've tried solving this by using my model for the node-colouring problem. It worked but I had to manually specify a new set of pairs in Exams x Exams that share students. I would like a model where I wouldn't have to do this and could instead just use the set Enrolled.

One of my constraints thus becomes:

```
subject to different_timeslots {t in TimeSlots, j in Students}:
    sum {i in Exams : (i,j) in Enrolled} x[i,t]<= y[t];
```

I'm using the CPLEX solver and I don't get any error messages; in fact, the objective function value is correct. However, several exams that share students are scheduled in the same time slot. I've tried fiddling with logical constraints instead (if..then) but to no avail.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Use the `expand` command to check what AMPL generates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did just that and found that the issue lied in how I had specified the set Enrolled. I transposed the matrix and viola, problem solved.

Comment: there are many way to do that. you can define a 2 dimensional set